# who are people Devs/techies should follow on twitter/ facebook?

Tags: twitter

yesterday i was reading an article that touched on twitter and made mention of how it can be influential if someone like Tim O'Reilly makes a suggestion then his 1.5 million followers on twitter will react to such tweets and cause some sort of reaction.

weather tweets and/ or the entire online social media ecosystem is debatable to no end it is a means of staying informed, sort of like watching the morning news.

this thought has sparked me to create a twitter account so that i can follow current events in what im interested in, namely software development and technology in general.

this brings me to my current situation of what intelligent people are worth following and listening too. i know the social media web is flooded with mind numbing nonsense but in part there are movers and shakers like Tim O'Reilly who are well worth listening too if for nothign more than getting a sense of which direction the wind is blowing.

so the million dollar question is who do you follow regularly?

please list the moniker of the person for others (ME) to be able to easily add & follow them as well... also list the medium (facebook/ twitter...)

in particular im interested in these technologies(MS SQL, asp.net/ C#)

thanks all for helping me get off to a fast start.

Comment: This would be a good question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ if it's not asked there already.

Answer (score 2):

The standard ones are problably something like:

- haacked
- jonskeet
- spolsky
- scottgu

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly your what you are looking for, but I would also consider blogs as well if I were you, which I find much more in depth and easier to follow than tweets.  I would certainly add Scott Hanselman to the list of people you follow.

Blog:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/

Twitter handle:  shanselman

Answer (score 1):

The two that top my list:

- martinfowler
- unclebobmartin